# Define global route for REST API controller

Tags: c#, routes, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-6.0, asp.net-apicontroller

I have the following case: in .NET framework there was the possibility to define a global route for API controllers and their methods. By getting the defaults and add a controller route you could leave out the [Route] attribute for the controllers. In addition to that, the route for the methods was adapted from the name of the method, so you could exclude the [Route] attribute there too.

So when you mapped for example "{controller}" and have a controller called "MyController" + have a method called "Post" and a method called "Delete" you just have to use the route "MyController" and depending on the action that is chosen either the "Post" method or the "Delete" method was called.

I want to reach the same in .NET 6 but I'm not sure how to achieve that here.

I've tried the following:

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    IDictionary<string, object> defaults = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    defaults.Add("controller", "{controller}");

    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(name: "default", pattern: "{controller}", defaults: defaults);
    endpoints.MapControllers();
});
```

Didn't work so far. As soon as I start my rest service I get the error that the [Route] attribute is missing.
Any ideas how to achieve that?

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you are looking for a definition of the default conventional routing.

You can define it like in example below:

```cs
app.MapControllers();
app.UseRouting();
app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=your_default_controller}/{action=defaul_action}/{id?}");
```

But you should take to account, that using the conventional routing for the REST API isn't the best solution. The Microsoft documentation recommend to use [attribute routing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-7.0#attribute-routing-for-rest-apis).

*NOTE: If you are going to use the conventional routing like defined above you should remove the `[ApiController]` and the `[Route("[controller]")]` attributes, that usually is added by default .NET REST API template.*

See the additional article:

[Attribute routing for REST APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-7.0#attribute-routing-for-rest-apis)

[Set up conventional route](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-7.0#set-up-conventional-route)